# Determine the number of ways to go from $(1,1)$ to $(n,1)$ on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinations, puzzle, chessboard

**Problem:** Let $S$ be a $n \times 3$ chessboard. Let a rook walk on the board, it is allowed to move $1$ step horizontally or vertically every step. Determine the number of ways the rook can go from the bottom left corner $(1,1)$ to the bottom right corner $(n,1)$ such that the rook has been on every square of the board exactly once (so in this context $(1,1)$ is a square for example)

**My question:** I don't know how start start in a structured manner for this one. Can anyone help me/give me tips or the full solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can the rook ever move right in the middle row?  (Try drawing out a few paths and see if you can find some patterns in the rook's movement)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. What I noticed was: you always go up 2 times, go right 3 times (2 times in the upper row, 1 time in the lowest row),go left 1 time in the middle row and go down 2 twice, but what can I do with that in order to determine a certain amount?@BrianMoehring

Comment: Here's a bigger hint: The rook path is comprised of two types of sequences of moves.  It starts on the bottom (resp. top) row, moves $k$ steps right (where $k\geq 0$), up (resp. down) one space, left $k$ spaces, up (resp. down) one space, and right $k$ spaces.  If it's not at the end, it moves right one space and repeats the same pattern again.  --- Break the path up into these blocks.  Can you count how many ways we can break the $n\times 3$ board up to end at $(n,1)$?

Comment: **Hint.** Let $a_n$ denote the number of ways to go from $(1,1)$ to $(n,1)$.  We also define $b_n$ to be the number of ways to go from $(1,1)$ to $(n,3)$.  Show that the sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}$ have the following interdependent recursive relations: $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\,b_k$$ and $$b_n=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\,a_k\,,$$ with $a_1=0$ and $b_1=1$.  Use these equations to show that $a_n=b_n=2^{n-2}$ for all integers $n\geq 2$.

Comment: @Batominovski I dont understand how you can conclude that a_n is the sum of b_k's,it is not intuitively clear to me why that holds

Comment: To calculate $a_n$, suppose that $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that the rook visits the squares $(k+1,1)$,(k+2,n), $\ldots$, $(n,1)$ consecutively.  Then, the rook must visit the squares $(k,3)$, $(k+1,3)$, $(k+2,3)$, $\ldots$, $(n,3)$, $(n,2)$, $(n-1,2)$, $\ldots$, $(k+2,2)$, $(k+1,2)$, $(k+1,1)$, $(k+2,1)$, $\ldots$, $(n,1)$ consecutively.  Hence, the rook must find a path from $(1,1)$ to $(k,3)$ within a $k$-by-$3$ square.  For a given $k$, this means there are $b_k$ ways to do so.

Comment: Use a similar argument to find the expression for $b_n$.  There is one small twist for $b_n$ (notice that it has an extra $1$ in the summation).

Comment: I see 2 potential problems with this argument: you base your argument on the assumption that the last few steps are always (q,1) squares. But take for example the 5x3 board. Then there is a way that has (n,3),(n,2) as its last two steps. Secondly, you say that you have to find the amount of ways in the k x 3 square to go from (1,1) to (k,3), but you also say that the last few steps are from (k,1) to (k+1,1) etc. The problem is now that you can find a path from (1,1) to (k,3) where you beforehand cross the (k,1) square such that you cant cross it again for its last steps.@Batominovski

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** It is an intuition, but for topological reasons, it seems to me that the simplest way to go from $(1, 1)$ to $(n, 1)$ is to follow the pattern
\begin{equation}
R^{k-1} U L^{k-1} U R^{n-1} D L^{n-k-1} D R^{n-k-1}
\end{equation}
where $1\le k\le n-1$ and $R, U, L, D$ mean go right, up, left, down respectively. Let us call this pattern $P_{n, k}$.

It seems reasonable to think that the only way to go from $(1, 1)$ to $(n, 1)$ is a composition of the form
\begin{equation}
P_{n_1, k_1} R P_{n_2, k_2} R\cdots R P_{n_j, k_j}
\end{equation}
where $n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_j = n$. If this is true, the number of ways to go from $(1,1)$ to $(n, 1)$ would be
\begin{equation}
N(n) =\sum_{n_1+\cdots+n_j = n\atop n_i\ge 2}(n_1-1)\cdots(n_j-1)
\end{equation}
Numerical investigations as well as a proof in the comments below indicate that this summation $N(n)$ reduces to $2^{n-2}$ as claimed by @Batominovski and @BrianMoehring

Comment: I don't know what your summation for $N$ can be simplified to, but I think the answer is $2^{n-2}$.

Comment: @Batominovski The path can be put into 1-1 correspondence, by looking at left endpoints on the middle row, with subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ containing $1$ and having an even number of elements, so it's **definitely** $2^{n-2}$ ;-)

Comment: @BrianMoehring  That is a nice bijective proof.  I got a proof with recursions (see my comment under the question).

Comment: @Batominovski I think the rook problem is now the intermediate step to prove that the above summation reduces to $2^{n-2}$

Comment: Write $N(n)$ for your expression.  Then, for $n\geq 2$, $$N(n)=(n-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\,(k-1)\cdot N(n-k)\,.$$  It is easily seen that $N(1)=0$, $$N(2)=1=2^{2-2}\,,$$ and $$N(3)=2=2^{3-2}\,.$$    Let $n>3$.  By induction, 
$$N(n)=(n-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\,(k-1)\cdot 2^{n-k-2}\,.$$
Therefore,
$$2\cdot N(n)=(2n-2)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}\,k\cdot 2^{n-k-2}\,.$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}N(n)&=2\cdot N(n)-N(n)\\&=n-1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}\,2^{n-k-2}-(n-3)\,.\end{align}$$
That is,
$$N(n)=2+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}\,2^{k}=2^{n-2}\,.$$